# Share a USB printer over Active Directory domain network

Tags: network, active-directory, domain

I would like to share a printer connected with the USB cable to my iMac with all the other Windows PCs that are part of a Windows Server 2016 Active Directory domain network.  Of course to do so, my iMac must be part of this network.

What I didn't understand is when can one say that an iMac is part of a domain network?  On Windows it is simple, just look at the information on the network and see if there is the word "domain network".

When on an iMac you go into the "network" setting and correctly insert IP, subnet, gateway (router on OS X?) and DNS (domain) can we already consider it part of the domain network? Or is it necessary to join the domain?

Ultimately, to share a printer from the iMac, is it sufficient to correctly configure the "network"?

Comment: Driving on the same streets doesn't mean you're part of all possible "networks" automatically (consider autobahn police ⇔ trucker/truckies/teamsters ⇔ highwaymen - sacking clueless tourists/truckers etc.) ;-).

Comment: @klanomath I did not understand the comparison

Comment: I just did the join (on mac it says binding?) of a Mac OS X 10.15.1 system to an Active Directory domain on Windows Server 2016.

In Active Directory management, the iMac was added to computers.

But I can't reach the iMac from any windows pc that is part of the domain.

Will it be due to the Mac OS X firewall? I don't think so, because it's disabled.

Comment: @nicovon Define "reach" for the studio audience, please.  You can't ping it?  You can't ping it by name?  You can't access some shared resource?

Comment: @MarcWilson https://imgur.com/ByXxiyp I have no ping problems. instead I can't access shared resources, in my case the printer.